# Where can I find State tax income rates from 1995 to present?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I'm working on a dataset for a longitudinal analysis and would like to add state income tax rate for the years 1995 to the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The taxfoundation.org provides this information going back to 2000. In addition to their interactive form, they have a downloadable Excel spreadsheet.

http://taxfoundation.org/article/state-individual-income-tax-rates